# Variation of Bin Packing Problem - Maximum # of one item in a single bin

Tags: python, r, mathematical-optimization, bin-packing

I have reviewed a lot of posts on Stack Overflow regarding the Bin Packing Problem and I haven't found this particular question asked. I have also looked for libraries out there in Python or R that handle this problem and haven't found any.

I have found many that handle the typical bin problem where you have a variety of items and bins and want to get as many items in a bin as possible.

My variation is simple. I have 1 item but an unlimited amount of it and I have 1 bin. I want to know what is the maximum amount of that 1 item I can fit in that bin. The item and the bin both have a height, length, and depth (weight is not important for my needs).

This might be such a simple optimization problem it doesn't even fall into the Bin Packaging Problem, but I'm apparently not smart enough to write the code.

Ideally I'm looking for a library or solution in Python/R since those are the languages I know and am comfortable with

Here's an example of the py3dbp library which solves the Bin Packing problem, but they have multiple items and multiple bins and put each item once. Again my example is 1 product going in a bin as many times as possible, which is impossible with this library.

```
from py3dbp import Packer, Bin, Item

packer = Packer()

packer.add_bin(Bin('small-envelope', 11.5, 6.125, 0.25, 10))
packer.add_bin(Bin('large-envelope', 15.0, 12.0, 0.75, 15))
packer.add_bin(Bin('small-box', 8.625, 5.375, 1.625, 70.0))
packer.add_bin(Bin('medium-box', 11.0, 8.5, 5.5, 70.0))
packer.add_bin(Bin('medium-2-box', 13.625, 11.875, 3.375, 70.0))
packer.add_bin(Bin('large-box', 12.0, 12.0, 5.5, 70.0))
packer.add_bin(Bin('large-2-box', 23.6875, 11.75, 3.0, 70.0))

packer.add_item(Item('50g [powder 1]', 3.9370, 1.9685, 1.9685, 1))
packer.add_item(Item('50g [powder 2]', 3.9370, 1.9685, 1.9685, 2))
packer.add_item(Item('50g [powder 3]', 3.9370, 1.9685, 1.9685, 3))
packer.add_item(Item('250g [powder 4]', 7.8740, 3.9370, 1.9685, 4))
packer.add_item(Item('250g [powder 5]', 7.8740, 3.9370, 1.9685, 5))
packer.add_item(Item('250g [powder 6]', 7.8740, 3.9370, 1.9685, 6))
packer.add_item(Item('250g [powder 7]', 7.8740, 3.9370, 1.9685, 7))
packer.add_item(Item('250g [powder 8]', 7.8740, 3.9370, 1.9685, 8))
packer.add_item(Item('250g [powder 9]', 7.8740, 3.9370, 1.9685, 9))

packer.pack()

for b in packer.bins:
    print(":::::::::::", b.string())

    print("FITTED ITEMS:")
    for item in b.items:
        print("====> ", item.string())

    print("UNFITTED ITEMS:")
    for item in b.unfitted_items:
        print("====> ", item.string())

    print("***************************************************")
    print("***************************************************")
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: As a hack (there should be optimizations you would be able to do), you could just loop and add the item `N` times, where `N = floor(total volume / item volume)`

Comment: I think the fact that your problem *refers* to actual bins may be misleading you to using the wrong kinds of algorithms. The bin packing problem is mostly about picking bins to try to fit items into, where "fit" is usually a trivial part of the problem (e.g. an simple volume comparison). Your actual problem seems to be more a geometry question, how many of a given shape can be packed in a larger shape. Because that's not the normal bin-packing problem, the algorithms used for the normal versions of the problem won't help you much.

Comment: perhaps try [BoxPacking](https://github.com/delta1epsilon/BoxPacking) for R, 1 or many bins, by volumetric fit as @Blckknght suggested, the ocean going container problem.